# PHP preg_match should be returning true but returning false

Tags: php, regex

so, I am trying to validate an id of 7 numbers. However, my code keeps returning the $idErr instead of the $id itself. I am not sure why, as I have verified that everything else is working and checked my regex in several validators. Any ideas? **Note: value I am entering is 9876543 which passes in any validator I use**

**see under //check id**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!--
    Turnin page example
    This page demonstrates a turnin form.
    The user can type in their personal info and turn in a fake homework assignment.
    -->
    <head>
        <title>Turnin Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
<?php

// define variables and set to empty values 
$studentname = $id = $assignment = $email = $cheat = " ";
$studentnameErr = $idErr = $assignmentErr = $emailErr = $cheatErr = " ";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    //your code goes here. 


    function test($data){
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    // check name
    if(empty($_POST["studentname"])) {
        $studentnameErr = "You need a name!";

    }elseif (!preg_match("/[a-z A-Z ]*$/",$studentname)) {
            $studentnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }else{
        $studentname = test($_POST["studentname"]);
        }

    // check id
    if(empty($_POST["id"])) {
        $idErr = "You need an id!";
    } elseif(!preg_match("/([0-9]{7})/",$id)){
        $idErr = "You need an id consisting of 7 numbers"; 
        } else{
            $id = test($_POST["id"]);
        }

    //check email 
    if(empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "You need an email!";
    }

    elseif(!preg_match("/[([a-z]{2}\d{4}a{1}@american.edu{1})]/", $email)) {
        $emailErr = "email needs to be: 2 consonants + 4 numbers + a@american.edu "; 

    } else{
        $email = test($_POST["email"]); 
        }

    //check assignment
    // check if a file has been uploaded and if the file name is hw1, hw2,
    if(empty($_POST["assignment"])) {
        $assignmentErr = "You need to submit an assignment!";
    } else{
        $assignment = test($_POST["assignment"]);

    }


    // check cheating

    if(empty($_POST["cheat"])) {
        $cheatErr = "You need to say you won't cheat!";
        } else{
            $cheat = test($_POST["cheat"]);
        }

    // note you need to use $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]
    // to access your file. 


    }
?>
<h1>CSC 435 Turnin</h1>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Personal Information</legend>
                <div>
                    Name: <input type="text" name="studentname"/>
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $studentnameErr;?></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Student id: <input type="text" name="id" maxlength="7"/>
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $idErr;?></span>
                </div>

                <div>
                    Student email: <input type="text" name="email"/>
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Assignment Information</legend>
                <div>
                    Assignment:
                    <label><input type="radio" name="assignment" value="1" /> 1</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="assignment" value="2" /> 2</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="assignment" value="3" /> 3</label>
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $assignmentErr;?></span>
                </div>


                <div>
                    Code:
                    <input type="file" name="code" />
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cheat" /> I promise I didn't cheat!
            </div>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $studentname;
echo "<br>";
echo $id;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $assignment;
echo "<br>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no reason to add the space character to your character class two times.  Your pattern is checking that there are zero or more characters at the end of your string.  You should also be using the starting anchor (`^`).  If you are not grabbing any characters in your `preg_` call, don't use capturing groups -- they only slow down your pattern.  You should run a bunch of test on regex101 and see what is wrong with your patterns and how to improve them.  `a{1}` is the same as `a` -- so don't use `{1}` ...ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are checking `$id` without assigning it. Either check `$_POST["id"]` or assign `$id` with `$_POST["id"]` value.

This would have shown you:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: id in file on line X

Comment: forgive me, I forgot to post my entire program. I am defining $id earlier

Comment: Yes but you are defining it as `" "` which doesn't match the pattern.

Comment: It doesn't change the problem. What you are trying to check is the input value. Replacing $id with $_POST['id] will still solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try `/^[a-z A-Z ]*$/` instead of `/[a-z A-Z ]*$/`, adding the ^